# Can't find resource for bundle android.icu.impl.ICUResourceBundleImpl$ResourceTable, key iw_IL

Tags: android, android-studio, debugging

I got this error when I debug the program. in real time everything is normal

[image]

Comment: Please add your code. And error logs.

Comment: it was classpath build issue. I solved that by this article: https://blogs.oracle.com/chengfang/solve-javautilmissingresourceexception:-cant-find-bundle-for-base-name-comconfig,-locale-zhcn thanks a lot anyway

Comment: May I ask for more information @Yaffa ? I have the same issue and the article is no longer available...